# ASP .Net Core - Inheriting from RazorPage<TModel> issue

Tags: asp.net-core, custom-view

I'm trying to define a base page by inheriting from RazorPage. If I pass anything other than TModel in my @inherit section of the page, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentException: Property 'ViewData' is of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary`1[[MyProject.Models.IndexViewModel, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]', but this method requires a value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
```

Parameter name: viewContext

How can I override **ViewData** so I can pass my custom model instead of **IndexViewModel** in the following line:

**@inherits MyProject.Base.BaseView**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I have done this to get around this issue, no idea whether it is a good or bad approach but is working

instead of actually using TModel in the RazorPage, use object for the generic type in RazorPage (RazorPage) and create a property to expose your own Model of the type you requested and cast Model to that type.

like this:

```
 public abstract class MenuViewPage<TModel> : RazorPage<object>
    {
        public TModel PageModel {
            get
            {
                return (TModel)ViewData.Model;
            }
        }

    }
```